# Problem in installing windows from bootable pendrive

Tags: dual-boot

As i have mentioned ; i am getting problem in installing windows in linux bases OS. Previously i had dual boot PC but then i tried to uninstall windows to keep only ubuntu. i deleted NTFS partition and then when i rebooted my pc it  was firstly showing **grub rescue** res mode.....then i thought to install new OS because i was having my backup in external hard disk. when i tried to install windows 10 by pendrive then it started showing " operating system not found".

my first preference is usb hdd SO It wont be a problematic thing. 
 my lenovo VERSION IS T410 so When is Tried to change boot mode it showed "DIAGNOSTICS" . i cant find the legacy mode so help me to come out from this problem.

**MY PC IS : LENOVO T410**

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using the ubuntu utility `boot repair` which can update your boot up grub after it probes for all available installed OS  just have your usb with windows plugged in ... I have had success with this tool on a dual boot issue yet I do not know if it can handle finding a OS on a usb drive